# Make multiple text passages take up same space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a page with a bunch of items on it with differing headings and text. I want the headings and text to all line up at the same height. Some headings will be 2 lines, some only 1. It needs to also be responsive, so I can't just set a min-height.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/cw1tl2gq.vhr.jpg))</sub>

Is it possible to get the h2's and p's to always be the same height? The hacky way I was thinking was padding out the shorter ones with javascript, but that is a last resort.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="itemContainer" style="width:25.0%;">
<div class="catItemView groupPrimary">
    <div class="catItemHeader">
        <h3 class="catItemTitle">
            <a href="/index.php/projects/item/46-wairamarama-onewhero-seal-extension">Wairamarama-Onewhero Seal Extension</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="catItemBody">
        <div class="catItemImageBlock">
            <span class="catItemImage">
                <a href="/index.php/projects/item/46-wairamarama-onewhero-seal-extension" title="Wairamarama-Onewhero Seal Extension">
                    <img src="/media/k2/items/cache/64d93d666355a43c4a86679a030d35b6_M.jpg" alt="Wairamarama-Onewhero Seal Extension" style="width:359px; height:auto;" />
                </a>
            </span>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="catItemIntroText">
            <p>Evergreen Landcare have been involved in the Wairamarama-Onewhero Seal Extension as a sub-contractor for Heb Construction.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div class="catItemReadMore">
        <a class="k2ReadMore" href="/index.php/projects/item/46-wairamarama-onewhero-seal-extension">Read more...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

This is generated by K2/Joomla! so there isn't much flexibility in it.
[This is the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625004243/http://test.evergreenlandcare.co.nz:80/index.php/projects) if you want to see it.

Comment: Are you asking for all the text to be visible at all times?

Comment: please add html markup

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript, you may need to resort to a table.

Comment: Or a css grid framework like Twitter Bootsrap or 960.gs

Comment: or simply add `height: __px` to a certain element or manipulate `display` property of some elements.

Comment: You will receive better results if you add a live demo on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Added a link at the bottom. The page is generated so it would take a bit to get it all working on a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "fix" the appearance by setting the height of the elements that have variable content to some value that  holds the largest.  The follwoing CSS does this for the page you linked to:

```
div.catItemIntroText {
  height: 180px;
}
div.catItemHeader h3.catItemTitle {
  height: 45px;
}
```

This only works because you know in advance the height that looks best.

If you were in a position to alter your HTML you could take a fresh approach and use a grid system.  Here is an approach that uses Twitter Bootstrap ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2vCj/))

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
             <h2>Wairamarama-Onewhero Seal Extension</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="span3">
             <h2>Te Rapa Pass</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="span3">
             <h2>Stockton Mine</h2>

        </div>
        <div class="span3">
             <h2>State Highway 88 Dunedin Realignment</h2>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3 ReadMore">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3 ReadMore"> <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>read more</a>

        </div>
        <div class="span3 ReadMore"> <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>read more</a>

        </div>
        <div class="span3 ReadMore"> <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>read more</a>

        </div>
        <div class="span3 ReadMore"> <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>read more</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By putting each row (of text, images and buttons) on it's own `<div.row>` the spill over is handled automatically.

Comment: I cannot implement this in Joomla!/K2.

Comment: I added some CSS that you can add quickly that will make your page flow cleanly (but it is a hack, in that you need to find the values that work based on the content you have)

Comment: Wouldn't setting the height screw with the responsiveness?

Comment: Well you could save the height with media queries (embracing the responsiveness and the hack), but this would make maintenance even harder.  Honestly I'd scrap the HTML and start over with a a responsive grid system (in am manor similar to the Twitter Bootstrap approach).  Sorry if this isn't helpful, this is just how I have solved problems like this in the past.

Comment: Yeah, if this wasn't paid work to be done in a particular framework with particular libraries I would have solved this ages ago. I was hoping there was a trick to make a block of text take up x amount of lines or something. I'll dig through the 20 stylesheets and set the height. Thanks.

Comment: This did it for me: div.itemContainer { height: 600px; }
div.catItemHeader { height: 100px; }